# How should I switch between different user environments in yaml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

In my rails application I have 2 users with 2 different API tokens, I need to switch back to user2 token seamlessly on application startup?

**config/tokens.yml**

```
development: &development
      # token belongs to user1
      api_token: 'token1'
      # token belongs to user2
      # api_token: 'token2'
      protocol: 'http'
      host: 'localhost'
      port: '3000'
```

How should I modify yaml file, so that selection between these users can be done easily.

Comment: The API tokens should be stored in your database if you want them to vary depending on which user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
api_users: user1,user2
api_tokens: token1,token2
```

Then when parsing the YAML, assuming the hash is stored in the `tokens` variable

```
def token_for_user(user)
  users = tokens[:api_users].split(",")
  tokens = tokens[:api_tokens].split(",")

  tokens[users.index(user)]
end

token_for_user("user1")
# => token1
```